# Using Spotify with PageFragment

Tags: android, spotify, background-process, android-tabs, background-music

I'm trying to hook up Spotify with my Android app. I want to be able to hit a button and have the user be able to start playing from their library on the 4th tab of the TabLayout, and have the ability to swipe back and forth from one tab to another without the music stopping. Here is my current view:

[Tabbed View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxfK7.png)

When I hit start broadcast, I just have it hooked up to SpotifyActivity.java where I've logged in and it starts playing a song. However, I want to have it so that I don't have to invoke a new activity when I want to start accessing my library and playing music so that I can switch between tabs and use the rest of the functionality of the app while the music plays. I recently learned about Services in Android and I was wondering if there was a way to use that. I basically want the flow to be like this:

The 4th tab presents a "start broadcast" button. Once this is hit, you log in to Spotify (or continue if you're already logged in), and a new view (activity?) pops up that gets Spotify and a UI working. Once the music starts, I can switch back to any of the first three tabs and interact with those while the music plays, and then when I go back to the first tab the activity pops up again with the music player UI and Spotify stuff. Here is my code for PageFragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private static User thisUser;

    private int mPage;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page, User localUser) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        thisUser = localUser;
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = null;
        TextView textView;
        if (mPage == 1) {

            //inflate the fragment_home_page

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);

            //handle profile and username information

        }
        else if (mPage == 2) {
            //inflate the fragment_play_page
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play_page, container, false);
            //handle music library information
        }
        else if(mPage == 3) {
            //inflate the fragment_live_page
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live_page, container, false);
            //handle live information
        }
        else if (mPage == 4) {
            //inflate the fragment_nowplaying_page
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nowplaying_page, container, false);

            Button startBroadcast = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.start_broadcast);

            //Links to SpotifyActivity
            startBroadcast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SpotifyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            Log.e("PageFragment ", "Unknown error occurred");
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is my code for SpotifyActivity:

```
public class SpotifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SpotifyPlayer.NotificationCallback, ConnectionStateCallback {

    //CLIENT_ID=
    //Callback

    // Request code that will be used to verify if the result comes from correct activity
    // Can be any integer
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1337;


    private Player mPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spotify);

        AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID,
                AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN,
                REDIRECT_URI);
        builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming"});
        AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

        AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //After the user logs in to authorize the application's scopes

        // Check if result comes from the correct activity
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);
            if (response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN) {
                Config playerConfig = new Config(this, response.getAccessToken(), CLIENT_ID);
                Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer spotifyPlayer) {
                        mPlayer = spotifyPlayer;
                        mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(SpotifyActivity.this);
                        mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(SpotifyActivity.this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Spotify.destroyPlayer(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Playback event received: " + playerEvent.name());
        switch (playerEvent) {
            // Handle event type as necessary
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackError(Error error) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Playback error received: " + error.name());
        switch (error) {
            // Handle error type as necessary
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoggedIn() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged in");

        mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V", 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoggedOut() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged out");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailed(Error error) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Login failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTemporaryError() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Temporary error occurred");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionMessage(String s) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Received connection message: " + s);
    }


}
```

Is there a way to set up Spotify's music player without losing it when I switch to other tabs?

Comment: Good question! Same here